# Building a complete multi-platform (android & web) chat app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, django, api, flutter

I want to build a chat app platform for both web and android. I want the chats and contents in the same database (kind of like telegram I guess?). What tools I should use for creating such a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Xamarin(language needed is C#)is a good framework for building Cross-platform apps
2-React Native( need some Javascript)
I will send you some links
This is for Xamarin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Er-ry99lS2k
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHHLyeak46E
You need to set up database :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows
3-setting/buildig up your web
I highly suggest .Net framework to build your web
To connect your web with app use API
from my experience i had good experience with APIs between .Net Web App and Xamarin Cross Platform App

Comment: Thanks man. I will use flutter for the mobile app most probably.

Comment: Flutter is faster and more easier to use ,                                 https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-chat-app-in-flutter-with-firebase-888b6222fe20                                                                                                                                                         My pleasure and good luck in you app                                                                                Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is definitely the go-to-technology for the frontend-part of such an application.

I assume you're about to start learning these technologies, thus I would recommend you to use Firebase for the backend-part. Firebase provides you with a realtime-database as well as storage. Using Firebase drastically reduces the effort needed to implemented the backend-part of your application in e.g. nodejs or something else. Since both Flutter and Firebase are backed by google, integrating the latter in the former is quite straightforward (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/).

https://www.cometchat.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chat-app-with-firebase